# Bootstrap show all dropdown on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want all of my dropdown menus to be displayed on hover in any of the menus. I have this code

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;    
}
```

But it works only on one menu item where my mouse is. I want all of them to show up. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post the put up a fiddle or atleast post the whole code? That will make out work little easier and which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: I using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Use a bit of jQuery to do this :

```
$("ul.nav").children("li.dropdown").hover(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.slideDown({duration: /*some duration in ms*/, queue: false});
  $("ul.dropdown-menu").each(function(index, elem){
    $(this).slideDown({duration: /*some duration in ms*/, queue: false});
  });
},function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.slideUp({duration: /*some duration in ms*/, queue: false});
  $("ul.dropdown-menu").each(function(index, elem){//index and elem are required by the each() function
    $(this).slideUp({duration: /*some duration in ms*/, queue: false});
  });
});
```

This should slide down everything on hover and slide up everything when mouse leaves (not hover anymore).

Comment: After move the mouse the main item being hide. any idea. We only need to hide the sub-item not the item itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant